# Spring - form with 2 modelAttributes

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security

I know how to use a form with 1 modelAttribute but how should I set 2 model attributes in same form ?

I have:

```
<sf:form id="details" action="/updateuser" method="POST" modelAttribute="updateuser">
    <sf:input type="text" name="firstName" path="firstName"/></br>
    <sf:input type="text" name="lastName" path="lastName" /></br>
    <sf:input type="text" name="email" path="email" /><sf:errors path="email" cssClass="error"></sf:errors> </br>

    <sf:input type="text" name="facebook" path="facebook" /> </br>
    <sf:input type="text" name="twitter" path="twitter" /> </br>
</sf:form>
```

`firstName` `lastName` and `email` are for `modelAttribute="updateuser"` but I need another `modelAttribute` for `facebook` and `twitter`

How should I implement this ?

Thanks!

EDIT: 
Isn't there any other way to do this without a wrapper class ? For more info, I have:

```
class User {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
}
class SocialMedia {
    private String facebook;
    private String twitter;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't attach more than one object to the `<form>`. However, you can create an explicit model class for the form and attach it.

```
class UpdateUserFormModel {

  private Updateuser updateuser;

  private Facebook facebook;

  private Twitter twitter;

}
```

You can access nested objects using `.` operator

```
<sf:input type="text" name="firstName" path="updateuser.firstName"/></br>
<sf:input type="text" name="facebook" path="facebook" /> </br>
```

Comment: Isn't there any other way to do this without a wrapper class ?

Comment: There is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't have more than one model attribute for one form, but you can use a wrapper to wrap your models.

```
class Wrapper {
private Class1 c1;
private Class2 c2;
....
//getter&setters
}
```

However, you are allowed to bind several objects to the same model using

```
model.addObject("objectName",object);
```

and access the objects in your page by

```
${objectName.name }
```

Comment: Isn't there any other way to do this without a wrapper class ?

Comment: Well, I don't think so. One form, one model attribute.